# appending script elements to execute code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code:

```
(function() {
    var myScript = document.createElement('script');
    myScript.src = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/test.js';
    setTimeout(function(){document.head.appendChild(myScript)}, 2000);
})()
```

where the js file in 'https://www.somewebsite.com/test.js' has the following content:

```
alert('hello');
```

If I open the developer console, and paste the code on the top, everything works perfectly. After 2 seconds or so pass, I get an alert message saying 'hello'.

**however**, when I paste the following code:

```
(function() {
    var myScript = document.createElement('script');
    myScript.src = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/test.js';
    setTimeout(function(){document.head.appendChild(myScript)}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){document.head.appendChild(myScript)}, 4000);
})()
```

I only receive 1 alert message, I don't get a second one.

**QUESTION:** does anyone know why that is? I would assume that appending the script again would cause the website I am in to execute the code again, but it doesn't.

I understand that there are other methods to do this, however I am interested in knowing what is happening in this specific situation.

Comment: Your browser caches the script. If you use a different file in the second call or if you add a unique query string, it should work as you expect.

Comment: Why do not try creating a new script element?

Answer (score 2):

You're appending the same element twice. Look in the Elements panel after the script has been appended. Are there one or two instances of the script? My guess is that although you call `appendChild()` twice, the second call does nothing. You'd get the same behavior if you tried to append the same `p` tag twice into the body.

Code for trying this out that doesn't require an external script:

```
(function() {
    var myScript = document.createElement('script');
    myScript.text = "alert('hello');";
    setTimeout(function(){document.head.appendChild(myScript)}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){document.head.appendChild(myScript)}, 4000);
})();
```

Update:

Actually, the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) says that if the node is already a child of the node it's getting appended to, then the child is first removed from the parent, and then appended. Which makes sense.